# Can someone explain Navigator Class and Scaffold Class from Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

The Flutter documentation is so vague. Can you guys explain what Google is vaguely saying:

**Navigator Class**

> Many apps have a navigator near the top of their widget hierarchy in order to display their logical history using an Overlay with the most recently visited pages visually on top of the older pages.

1. What does it mean "near the top [...] in order to display their logical history"?
2. what does it mean by "logical history"?

**Scaffold Class**

> Implements the basic material design visual layout structure.

1. Why is the Scaffold class implementing material design? Isn't that the job of the MaterialApp class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Navigator

1. "Near the top" means near the root of the widget hierarchy. For example if you use `MaterialApp` it contains a Navigator that allows to switch between different pages.
   Near the top means that adding a different route overlays all of the screen, not just a small part like a popup. There can be additional Navigators inside such a page for example to overlay smaller parts of the view.
2. A bar with tabbar like functionality that allows to control which page the Navigator shows.
3. You can use the back button to navigate to the previous page.

Scaffold

1. MaterialApp is more about theme,
   Scaffold is more about structure of the screen. Where to position the AppBar, Drawer, content, ...

That they are different widgets makes it easier to replace one or the other with a custom implementation without the need to implement also the other in your custom implementation. Flutter is all about composability.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question! Now I understand the Scaffold definition. Thank you! For the navigator, I am stuck on the phrase "widget hierarchy". Does that mean the order the widgets are in listed in the code in the children parameter?

Comment: Yes, you might have something like `Page > Tab > TabBar (with tab headers as children) + TabContent > List > List items > ... . You can imagine the content of the view like a tree of widgets, like HTML is a tree of elements.
The root widget fills the whole screen, children only parts of their parents.

Comment: Okay awesome. So let me summarize what I understand:
Navigator is listed first (before any other widget) in the tree so that when it overlays new pages it is above all widgets in the app -- which is referred by "widget hierarchy". The term "logical history" basically refers to the stacking of new pages in chronological order -- the top page being the most recently overlayed. Can you confirm I understood everything properly? :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct, just that "Navigator is listed first" is not strictly the first, but "near the top", but it's usually the top-most visual widget. There can be non-visuals like `MediaQuery`, `Directionality`, `Theme`, ... above the navigator.

Comment: Thank you so much Gunter! I really appreciate your help! You have been extremely helpful! :)